# Keyboard shows too slow when typing at an edittext inside SlidingMenu

Tags: android, android-edittext, slidingmenu

I'm using Sliding Menu library at: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/. But when I try to type at editexts that I placed inside this sliding menu, the keyboard showing too slow as the whole screen is freezing during that time. It's a little discomforting.

If there are anyone knew or experienced this issue, please let me know how to fix it. Thank you.

**LOG CAT:**

```
com.example.myapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 18.127ms
com.example.myapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 82503(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 24(384KB) LOS objects, 7% free, 46MB/50MB, paused 2.960ms total 129.150ms
com.example.myapp D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
com.example.myapp D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
com.example.myapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 86690(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 4(64KB) LOS objects, 26% free, 45MB/61MB, paused 4.180ms total 175.140ms
com.example.myapp D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
com.example.myapp D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

That's the logcat when I open, then close the soft keyboard.

Comment: Did you check the `LogCat` ? Does it say something along the lines of `The application is doing too much work, skipped XXX frames` ?

Comment: This is what's at the LogCat: "Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 48409(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 4(64KB) LOS objects, 4% free, 52MB/55MB, paused 9.033ms total 140.289ms"

Comment: Also: "Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 64974(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 50MB/66MB, paused 3.692ms total 173.614ms"